# What does @ do in scala

Tags: scala

On line 229 of https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala

```
  case j @ ExtractEquiJoinKeys(joinType, leftKeys, rightKeys, nonEquiCond,
```

There is a usage of @, and I can't quite find the definition in https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html

What is its usecase of @ in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

This is called a pattern binder. See section 8.1.3 of [the language spec](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html)

Directly copying from the language spec

> A pattern binder x@p consists of a pattern variable
> x and a pattern p. The type of the variable x is the static type T implied by the pattern p. This pattern matches any value v matched by the pattern p, and it binds the variable name to that value.

A pattern p implies a type T if the pattern matches only values of the type
T.

In more practical terms, in allows you to "unpack" the constructor in the form of a pattern and gives you fine grained control over the matching. You can unpack it in terms of symbols (variables), static values or as other nested patterns while keeping the original object bound to variable x

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the Pattern Matching section: https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-binders

(I'm not sure whether you linked to the Lexical Syntax section of the spec specifically because that's where you were looking, or that was intended as representative of the entire spec)

> A pattern binder `x@p` consists of a pattern variable `x` and a pattern `p`

It simply allows you to *both* write a specific pattern to be matched (e.g. by the `case` expression), while also binding a variable to the value that matched the whole pattern.

Without the pattern binder syntax, you could write a simple pattern consisting of a single variable which would give you easy access to the whole value but doesn't impose a requirement to match a more-specific pattern, *or* you could write a more complex pattern but then would not have access to the whole value (without duplicating some code to reconstruct it from the parts you bound in the pattern). Pattern binder syntax allows you to do both at once, without repetition.